# WCF Service - Preventing errors being passed to client

Tags: wcf, custom-errors

I've got a WCF service which swallows up exceptions thrown in called methods and passing them on to the client. This is fine for DEBUG mode, and I've got a feeling I turned this functionality on, but how do you turn it off?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to put more information into your question to get a meaningful answer. A good start would be the service configuration, code or app.config/web.config file.

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650331.aspx: Do not divulge exception error details to clients in production.

Comment: @MortenFrederiksen, that is why he posted the question. I got the memo about the TPS reports. I have it right here, I just...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` attribute of the `serviceDebug` element in the web.config file for your service. Setting this attribute to "false" should prevent exception details from being returned to the client.

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="httpsBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```